# How do I get filename/file extension of a file on the Desktop in win7 which I drag?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I'm working on a project which is a tiny tool running in the background. It only has a taskbar icon most of the time.

And it will record user mouse activities on the desktop(which is explorer.exe). Now I can get desktop mouse activities by making a DLL using c++ and use setWindowsHookEx() to set a global hook.

Question is, when people drag desktop icons and files on the desktop, when they dragging, how can I get the filename and extension of the file they are dragging?

Comment: That's not possible, D+D is not hookable.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Considering the Drag Source is Explorer.EXE in this case, why not? It's a COM host for Shell Extensions. Just detour (in-process) `RegisterDragDrop` and grab the filename(s).

Comment: Hmm, yeah, why not?  Maybe because the OP likes keeping his hair...